# change file-name with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**My main question is**, for security reasons, I'd like to know if it's possible to virtually change the name (in a sense) of a website file using .htaccess. For instance, if I have a file `/index.php` and I want to make it such that calls for `/mysite` are redirected to `/index.php`, but I *also* want calls to `/index.php` to return as either an error 403 or 404. Is this possible? And if so, how could it be done?
Also, I've been searching for a full documentation on the .htaccess directive syntax, but I couldn't find anything. **My second question is**, Does anyone know of a good generic reference of all the directives and their syntax? (I couldn't even find one in w3schools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll start by saying w3schools doesn't have particularly good references for anything.  The [Apache mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is really good, and I always go there first.

The first part of your request is pretty straightforward as a rewrite. But before we get there, let's start by preventing direct requests to `index.php`.  In order to do this without messing up our other rules we will use the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable to match `index.php` and forbid access.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request sent by the browser includes index.php...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
# forbid access (403)
RewriteRule ^. - [F]

# Then you just need a generic rule to rewrite /mysite into index.php
RewriteRule ^mysite index.php [L]
```

We need the first part using `THE_REQUEST` to avoid causing conflicts with the second part rewriting into index.php.

If you want to serve a 404 to make it look like `index.php` doesn't even exist, replace the `[F]` with `[R=404,L]`